# UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'helpBot' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a bot in python via telebot. I needed a check for the “Paid” command, but something went wrong.

```
@bot.message_handler() 
def help(m):    
    if m.text == 'I paid':
        global help_user_id
        help_user_id = m.from_user.id
        msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Describe your cover')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, help, helpBot)
        def helpBot(m):
            bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, m.chat.id, m.message_id)
            @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
            def handle_text(m):
                if int(m.chat.id) == int(TO_CHAT_ID):
                    bot.send_message(help_user_id, m.text)
```

Error: UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'helpBot' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: You need to define `helpBot` before you use it as a function argument. Move the `def` line to the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The `helpbot()` function should be defined outside or before it's called, preferably placed outside the current context. This ensures that Python can recognize and access `helpbot()` when needed. Think of it like explaining the meaning of an unfamiliar term "uiuerwjdims" before asking a question about it; having the context in place makes it clearer. Additionally, it's a good practice to avoid nesting functions when possible, unless it's a callback function where passing arguments is challenging, in which case, a [lambda](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-lambda-function-explained/) function may be used.